# any one can provide me code for chat message auto refreshing using ajax for ror tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'www.lockated.com/chat_agent' success: function(data) { $('#messages').html(data); } }); 
  }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: if you can provide enough monetary incentive I'm sure someone could provide code for you

Comment: You can use the nodejs, socket-io, websockets for real time chat application with ror.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `websockets` or `plezi` gem or the `ActionCable` of `Rails 5.0` for your particular task.

I have implemented the same chat application with auto-refresh , same as facebook chat which you will find [here](https://github.com/huzefahuzu/Advanced-ChatApp-with-Instant-Replies-Using-Plezi-Gem-) .

Comment: i used 4.2 through out the my project.can you provide code without that gems

Comment: I personally have used `plezi` gem .It's very easy to integerate this gem in your current code and won't take much time . post your `controller` code from where you are saving the chats in the database , i will edit my answer and will guide you through to set it up working in your project.